# How can I automatically upload Facebook Live Videos to Twitter?

Tags: facebook, twitter, if-this-then-that, facebook-live-video

I recently started a new Daily Video project where I upload a Facebook Live Video every day. I would like to auto-sync these to my Twitter account.

I already have an ifttt recipe that syncs my Facebook posts to Twitter, but it doesn't seem to catch these videos. Is there a way, using ifttt or otherwise, to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the [Facebook to twitter](https://www.facebook.com/twitter) connection via Facebook? It offers to update your twitter with each status/photo/link/video/note/event.